# Installing ROS Indigo on NAO: problem with yaml

Tags: ros, yaml, ros-indigo, nao

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello

I'm trying to install ROS Indigo on a NAO V4 with OpenNao 1.14.5.

Following the tutorial "*Installation of ROS on the Nao robot*" (http://wiki.ros.org/nao/Installation/local) I had an issue starting ROS on NAO:

`roslaunch nao_bringup nao.launch` gives me the following output:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/openrobots/bin/roslaunch", line 34, in <module>
    import roslaunch
  File "/var/persistent/opt/openrobots/lib/python2.7/site-packages/roslaunch/__init__.py", line 51, in <module>
    from . import param_dump as roslaunch_param_dump
  File "/var/persistent/opt/openrobots/lib/python2.7/site-packages/roslaunch/param_dump.py", line 40, in <module>
    import roslaunch.config
  File "/var/persistent/opt/openrobots/lib/python2.7/site-packages/roslaunch/config.py", line 45, in <module>
    import rospkg.distro
  File "/var/persistent/opt/openrobots/lib/python2.7/site-packages/rospkg/distro.py", line 44, in <module>
    import yaml
ImportError: No module named yaml
```

I tried to re-install yaml (`sudo emerge pyyaml`) and got this error as a result:

```
ERROR: app-admin/eselect-python-20100321 failed (setup phase):
 *   GCC >=3.4 is required
 * 
 * Call stack:
 *     ebuild.sh, line  75:  Called pkg_setup
 *   environment, line 636:  Called die
 * The specific snippet of code:
 *           die "GCC >=3.4 is required";
```

Therefore has anyone an idea of how to correctly install pyyaml on NAO?

Thank You very much :)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/196887/installing-ros-indigo-on-nao:-problem-with-yaml/) by [Schwartzmuller](https://answers.ros.org/users/20683/schwartzmuller/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2014-11-06

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I don't know if you fixed your problem yet but to install pyyaml on your virtual nao you need to use
sudo easy_install pyyaml

If you want a complete tutorial to setup ROS on your NAO is available here : http://wiki.ros.org/nao/Installation/compileFromVirtualNao
I didn't validated it on 1.14 because I'm using ROS Indigo which is not compatible with NAOqi < 2.0. But this should work.

Hope this helps,

Mikael

---

Originally posted by [marguedas](https://answers.ros.org/users/19307/marguedas/) with karma: 3606 on 2014-12-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0